# Creating a trend line from data set SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio, math, linear-regression

The code below returns the number of resolved tickets and the number of opened tickets for a period (period is YYYY,WW) going back a certain number of days. For example if @NoOfDays is 7:

> resolved | opened | week | year | period
>
> 56 | 30 | 13 | 2012 | 2012, 13
>
> 237 | 222 | 14 | 2012 | 2012, 14

'resolved' and 'opened' are graphed on lines (y) over period (x). I would like to add another column 'trend' that would return a number that when graphed over period, will be a trend line (simple linear regression). *I **do** want to use both sets of values as one data source for the trend.*

This is the code I have:

```
SELECT a.resolved, b.opened, a.weekClosed AS week, a.yearClosed AS year,
    CAST(a.yearClosed as varchar(5)) + ', ' + CAST(a.weekClosed as varchar(5)) AS period
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNbr) AS resolved, { fn WEEK(date_closed) } AS weekClosed, { fn YEAR(date_closed) } AS yearClosed
    FROM v_rpt_Service
    WHERE (date_closed >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - @NoOfDays, 0))
    GROUP BY { fn WEEK(date_closed) }, { fn YEAR(date_closed) }) AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNbr) AS opened, { fn WEEK(date_entered) } AS weekEntered, { fn YEAR(date_entered) 
    } AS yearEntered
    FROM v_rpt_Service AS v_rpt_Service_1
    WHERE        (date_entered > = DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - @NoOfDays, 0))
    GROUP BY { fn WEEK(date_entered) }, { fn YEAR(date_entered) }) AS b ON a.weekClosed = b.weekEntered AND a.yearClosed = b.yearEntered
ORDER BY year, week
```

**Edit:**

According to serc.carleton.edu/files/mathyouneed/best_fit_line_dividing.pdf, it seems that I want to break the data in half, then calculate the average. Then I need to find the best fit line, and use the slope and the y-intercept to calculate the values needed to return in 'trend' using `y = mx + b`?

I know this is very possible in SQL, however, the program I am inserting the SQL into has limitations on what I can do.

**The red and blue dots are the numbers I am returning now(opened and resolved). I need to return a value for every period in 'trend' in order to create the purple line. (this image is hypothetical)**

[image: Hypothetical Chart]

Comment: Is this for MS SQLServer, or for a different RDBMS?

Comment: MS SQLServer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I divided the data into multiple derived tables and sub queries, essentially dividing the data in half. These are my formulas to get each value:

```
*(each row is a week)*
y1 = average of data first half
y2 = average of data second half
x1 = 1/4 of number of weeks
x2 = 3/4 of number of weeks
m = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
b = y2 - (m * x2)
trend = (m * row_number) + b
```

And here is my (very dirty) SQL code:

```
SELECT  resolved_half1,resolved_half2,opened_half1,opened_half2, c.period,
((SUM (resolved_half1) OVER () + SUM(opened_half1) OVER ()) - (SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ())) / ((COUNT(resolved_half1) OVER () + COUNT(opened_half1) OVER ()) / 2) as y1, 
((SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ()) / (COUNT(resolved_half2) OVER () + COUNT (opened_half2) OVER ())) as y2,
((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) as x1,
(((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) * 3) as x2,
((CAST(((SUM (resolved_half1) OVER () + SUM(opened_half1) OVER ()) - (SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ())) / ((COUNT(resolved_half1) OVER () + COUNT(opened_half1) OVER ()) / 2) as float) - CAST(((SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ()) / (COUNT(resolved_half2) OVER () + COUNT (opened_half2) OVER ())) as float)) / (CAST(((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) as float) - CAST( (((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) * 3) as float))) as m,
(CAST(((SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ()) / (COUNT(resolved_half2) OVER () + COUNT (opened_half2) OVER ())) as float) - (((CAST(((SUM (resolved_half1) OVER () + SUM(opened_half1) OVER ()) - (SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ())) / ((COUNT(resolved_half1) OVER () + COUNT(opened_half1) OVER ()) / 2) as float) - CAST(((SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ()) / (COUNT(resolved_half2) OVER () + COUNT (opened_half2) OVER ())) as float)) / (CAST(((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) as float) - CAST( (((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) * 3) as float))) * (((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) * 3))) as b,
((((CAST(((SUM (resolved_half1) OVER () + SUM(opened_half1) OVER ()) - (SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ())) / ((COUNT(resolved_half1) OVER () + COUNT(opened_half1) OVER ()) / 2) as float) - CAST(((SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ()) / (COUNT(resolved_half2) OVER () + COUNT (opened_half2) OVER ())) as float)) / (CAST(((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) as float) - CAST( (((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) * 3) as float))) * (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.yearClosed,c.weekClosed))) + (CAST(((SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ()) / (COUNT(resolved_half2) OVER () + COUNT (opened_half2) OVER ())) as float) - (((CAST(((SUM (resolved_half1) OVER () + SUM(opened_half1) OVER ()) - (SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ())) / ((COUNT(resolved_half1) OVER () + COUNT(opened_half1) OVER ()) / 2) as float) - CAST(((SUM(resolved_half2) OVER () + SUM(opened_half2) OVER ()) / (COUNT(resolved_half2) OVER () + COUNT (opened_half2) OVER ())) as float)) / (CAST(((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) as float) - CAST( (((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) * 3) as float))) * (((COUNT(c.period) OVER ()) / 4) * 3)))) as trend,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.yearClosed,c.weekClosed) as row

FROM
    (SELECT *, CAST(yearClosed as varchar(5)) + ', ' + CAST(weekClosed as varchar(5)) AS period
     FROM  (SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNbr) AS resolved_half1, { fn WEEK(date_closed) } AS weekClosed, { fn YEAR(date_closed) } AS yearClosed
                          FROM            v_rpt_Service
      WHERE (date_closed >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - (180), 0))

      GROUP BY { fn WEEK(date_closed) }, { fn YEAR(date_closed) }) AS a 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNbr) AS opened_half1, { fn WEEK(date_entered) } AS weekEntered, { fn YEAR(date_entered) 
       FROM v_rpt_Service AS v_rpt_Service_1
       WHERE (date_entered > = DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - (180), 0))
       GROUP BY { fn WEEK(date_entered) }, { fn YEAR(date_entered) }) AS b ON a.weekClosed = b.weekEntered AND a.yearClosed = b.yearEntered) as c 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT *, CAST(yearClosed as varchar(5)) + ', ' + CAST(weekClosed as varchar(5)) AS period 
       FROM  (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNbr) AS resolved_half2, { fn WEEK(date_closed) } AS weekClosed, { fn YEAR(date_closed) } AS yearClosed
       FROM v_rpt_Service
       WHERE (date_closed >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - (180 / 2), 0))
       GROUP BY { fn WEEK(date_closed) }, { fn YEAR(date_closed) }) AS d 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(DISTINCT TicketNbr) AS opened_half2, { fn WEEK(date_entered) } AS weekEntered, { fn YEAR(date_entered)} AS yearEntered
       FROM v_rpt_Service AS v_rpt_Service_1
       WHERE (date_entered > = DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - (180 / 2), 0))
       GROUP BY { fn WEEK(date_entered) }, { fn YEAR(date_entered) }) AS e ON d.weekClosed = e.weekEntered AND d.yearClosed = e.yearEntered
) as f ON c.yearClosed = f.yearClosed AND c.weekClosed = f.weekClosed AND c.weekEntered = f.weekEntered AND c.yearEntered = f.yearEntered AND c.period = f.period
GROUP BY c.period, resolved_half1,resolved_half2,opened_half1,opened_half2,c.yearClosed,c.weekClosed
ORDER BY row
```

**This code uses a hard coded value of 180 days. I still need to be able to use a varibale to select the number of days (without getting a divide by 0 error), and the code really needs to be cleaned up. 
If someone can do those two things for me (I'm not the best at SQL), the bounty is theirs.**

Image:

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 6):

I was interested in the problem, and I have found that the best way to grok a complex query is to reformat it using my own style and conventions. I applied them to your solution, and the result is below. I've no idea if this will have any value to you...

- There were a few bits of code that I do not believe are part of the MS T-SQL syntax, such as `({fn xxx }` and the `WEEK(xxx)` function.
- This code compiles, but I can't run it as I don't have a data table properly configured.
- I made a host of coding changes that would take a serious lot of explaining, and I'm going to skip most of that.  Add a comment if you'd like anything explicated.
- I tossed in a lot of whitespace.  The difference between legible and illegible codes is often just the perception and sensibilities of the beholder, and you might hate my conventions.
- Not sure what the final result set should be (i.e. which columns get returned)

Some further notes:

- This query will not get items entered in a week if no items were also closed in that week
- Weeks may be partial, e.g. not all seven days may be present (adjust @Interval to always including full weeks -- but what about odd numbered intervals?)
- Multiply the count(*) values by 1.0 to convert them to floats early (avoids cast and integer math truncation)
- Made it a cte to allow the earlier formulas to be replaced by symbols in the later formulas (at which point things became a lot more legible)

So here's what I came up with:

```
;WITH cte as (
select
   c.period
  ,resolved_half1
  ,resolved_half2
  ,opened_half1
  ,opened_half2
  ,row = row_number() over(order by c.yearClosed, c.weekClosed)
  ,y1 = ((SUM(resolved_half1) + SUM(opened_half1)) - (SUM(resolved_half2) + SUM(opened_half2))) / ((count(resolved_half1) + count(opened_half1)) / 2)
  ,y2 = ((SUM(resolved_half2) + SUM(opened_half2)) / (count(resolved_half2) + COUNT (opened_half2)))
  ,x1 = ((count(c.period)) / 4)
  ,x2 = (((count(c.period)) / 4) * 3)
 from (select
          a.yearclosed
         ,a.weekClosed
         ,a.resolved_half1
         ,b.yearEntered
         ,b.weekEntered
         ,b.opened_half1
         ,cast(a.yearClosed as varchar(5)) + ', ' + cast(a.weekClosed as varchar(5))  period 
        from (--  Number of items per week that closed within @Interval
              select
                 count(distinct TicketNbr) * 1.0  resolved_half1
                ,datepart(wk, date_closed)        weekClosed
                ,year(date_closed)                yearClosed
               from v_rpt_Service 
               where date_closed >= @FullInterval
               group by
                 datepart(wk, date_closed)
                ,year(date_closed) )  a
         left outer join (--  Number of items per week that were entered within @Interval
                          select 
                             count(distinct TicketNbr) * 1.0  opened_half1
                            ,datepart(wk, date_entered)       weekEntered
                            ,year(date_entered)               yearEntered
                           from v_rpt_Service
                           where date_entered >= @FullInterval
                           group by
                             datepart(wk, date_entered)
                            ,year(date_entered) )  b
          on a.weekClosed = b.weekEntered 
           and a.yearClosed = b.yearEntered)  c
  left outer join (select
                       d.yearclosed
                      ,d.weekClosed
                      ,d.resolved_half2
                      ,e.yearEntered
                      ,e.weekEntered
                      ,e.opened_half2
                      ,cast(yearClosed as varchar(5)) + ', ' + cast(weekClosed as varchar(5))  period 
                    from (select
                             count(distinct TicketNbr) * 1.0  resolved_half2
                            ,datepart(wk, date_closed)        weekClosed
                            ,year(date_closed)                yearClosed
                           from v_rpt_Service
                           where date_closed >= @HalfInterval
                           group by
                             datepart(wk, date_closed) 
                            ,year(date_closed) )  d 
                     left outer join (select
                                         count(distinct TicketNbr) * 1.0  opened_half2
                                        ,datepart(wk, date_entered)       weekEntered
                                        ,year(date_entered)               yearEntered
                                       from v_rpt_Service
                                       where date_entered >= @HalfInterval
                                       group by
                                           datepart(wk, date_entered) 
                                          ,year(date_entered) )  e
                      on d.weekClosed = e.weekEntered
                       and d.yearClosed = e.yearEntered )  f
   on c.period = f.period 
 group by
   c.period
  ,resolved_half1
  ,resolved_half2
  ,opened_half1
  ,opened_half2
  ,c.yearClosed
  ,c.weekClosed
)
SELECT
   row
  ,Period
  ,x1
  ,y1
  ,x2
  ,y2
  ,m = ((y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2))
  ,b = (y2 - (((y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)) * x2))
  ,trend = ((((y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)) * (row)) + (y2 - (((y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)) * x2)))
 from cte
 order by row
```

As an addenda, all of subquery "c" could be replaced with something like the following, and "f" with a slightly modified version. Better or worse performance depends on table size, indexing, and other imponderables.

```
select
   datepart(wk, date_closed)  weekClosed
  ,year(date_closed)          yearClosed
  ,count (distinct case
                  when date_closed >= @FullInterval then TicketNbr
                  else null
                end)          resolved_half1
  ,count (distinct case
                  when date_entered >= @FullInterval then TicketNbr
                  else null
                end)          opened_half1
 from v_rpt_Service 
 where date_closed >= @FullInterval
  or date_entered >= @FullInterval
 group by
   datepart(wk, date_closed)
  ,year(date_closed)
```

Comment: An decade later you get an up vote for the effort involved in trying to help as well as the adding whitespace, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will do the trick - if not post some actual sample data and I'll see if I can tweak it to fix it:

```
DECLARE @noOfDays INT
SET @noofdays = 180

;WITH tickets AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT
DATENAME(YEAR,date_closed) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,date_closed) AS VARCHAR(5)),3) as Period
,ticket_nbr
,1 as ticket_type --resolved
FROM v_rpt_Service
WHERE (date_closed >= DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - @NoOfDays, 0)) 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
DATENAME(YEAR,date_closed) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,date_closed) AS VARCHAR(5)),3) as Period
,ticket_nbr
,0 as ticket_type --opened
FROM v_rpt_Service
WHERE  (date_entered > = DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GetDate()) - @NoOfDays, 0)) 
)
,tickets2 AS
(
SELECT
Period
,SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_type = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as opened
,SUM(CASE WHEN ticket_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as closed
FROM tickets
GROUP BY
Period
)
,tickets3 AS
(
SELECT
Period
,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY period ASC) as row
,opened
,closed
,COUNT(period) OVER() as base
,SUM(opened) OVER () as [Sumopened]
,SUM(opened * opened) OVER () as [Sumopened^2]
,SUM(opened * closed) OVER () as [Sumopenedclosed]
,SUM(closed) OVER () as [Sumclosed]
,SUM(closed * closed) OVER () as [Sumclosed^2]
,SUM(opened * closed) OVER () * COUNT(period) OVER () AS [nSumopenedclosed]
,SUM(opened) OVER () * SUM(closed) OVER () AS [Sumopened*Sumclosed]
,SUM(opened * opened) OVER () * COUNT(period) OVER () AS [nSumopened^2]
,SUM(opened) OVER () * SUM(opened) OVER () as [Sumopened*Sumopened]
FROM tickets2
)
--Formula for linear regression is Y = A + BX
SELECT
period
,opened
,closed
,((1.0 / base) * [Sumclosed]) - 
([Sumopenedclosed] - ([Sumopened*Sumclosed] / base)) / ([Sumopened^2] - ([Sumopened*Sumopened] / base)) *((1.0 / base) * [Sumopened]) 
+ row * ([Sumopenedclosed] - ([Sumopened*Sumclosed] / base)) / ([Sumopened^2] - ([Sumopened*Sumopened] / base))  
AS trend_point
,((1.0 / base) * [Sumclosed]) - 
([Sumopenedclosed] - ([Sumopened*Sumclosed] / base)) / ([Sumopened^2] - ([Sumopened*Sumopened] / base)) *((1.0 / base) * [Sumopened]) AS A
,([Sumopenedclosed] - ([Sumopened*Sumclosed] / base)) / ([Sumopened^2] - ([Sumopened*Sumopened] / base)) as B
from tickets3
```